# How many methods are there to add an element to a list and which is the fastest?

Tags: python, list

When I take a job interview I got a question about Python: how many methods are there to add an element to a list and which one of them is the fastest?

I know I can use list's methods such as `append`, `insert`, and of course `+`. So, is there any others? And which one is the fastest, why?

Comment: The fastest one will be the one that does not make a copy of the list

Comment: And does not require moving elements around.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's find out! This is using ipython's `%%timeit` magic function.

```
In [5]: %%timeit x = []
   ...: x = x + [1]
   ...:
10000 loops, best of 3: 21.5 us per loop

In [6]: %%timeit x = []
x.append(1)
   ...:
1000000 loops, best of 3: 93.7 ns per loop

In [7]: %%timeit x = []
x.insert(0, 1)
   ...:
100000 loops, best of 3: 30 us per loop

In [8]: %%timeit x = [1,2,3]
x.insert(len(x), 1)
   ...:
1000000 loops, best of 3: 293 ns per loop

In [9]: %%timeit x = []
x.extend([1])
   ....:
1000000 loops, best of 3: 208 ns per loop

In [15]: %%timeit x = []
x += [1]
   ....:
10000000 loops, best of 3: 165 ns per loop
```

So `append` is fastest, followed by `+=`, followed by `extend()`, followed by `insert`ing at the end of the list. This is because Python doesn't have to create a new list (like with `+`) or move all the elements (like with inserting at the beginning).

It's instructive to note that `x = x + [1]` is *over 200 times slower* than `x += [1]`. Keep that in mind next time performance really matters.

Now, this behavior may vary for appending very large lists. The difference isn't as dramatic:

```
In [17]: %%timeit y = []
y = y + range(1000000)
   ....:
10 loops, best of 3: 76.8 ms per loop

In [18]: %%timeit y = []
y += range(1000000)
   ....:
10 loops, best of 3: 23.4 ms per loop
```

but it certainly is in the case of appending **to** very large lists:

```
In [24]: %%timeit y = range(1000000)
y.append(1)
   ....:
10000000 loops, best of 3: 92.7 ns per loop

In [29]: %%timeit y = range(1000000)
y.insert(len(y), 1)
   ....:
1000000 loops, best of 3: 293 ns per loop

In [30]: %%timeit y = range(1000000)
y = y + [1]
   ....:
100 loops, best of 3: 12.6 ms per loop
```

That's a difference of **130,927** times in performance! And that's why this is an interview question.

Comment: Nice answer and I also thought `append` is the fastest. So is there any other method?

Answer (score 3):

`+` does not modify the original list; `+=` does. `+=` is the same thing as `extend`. Append, or inserting at the end is fastest, and has O(1) amortized time. Insertion in anywhere but the constant end in the list has O(n) time complexity.

Also notice that method lookup has a very significant performance impact, so the fastest code is actually

```
the_list = []
append = the_list.append

# later...
append(item)
```

if needed to do repeatedly for the same list.